# Why i should add dynamic web module when installing maven facet?

Tags: maven, myeclipse

I want to add **Maven facet** to some project in Eclipse, but when I do that, it adds **Dynamic Web Module** to the project.

The first question is **why** ?

Second is **how** can I make it without adding web module??

thanks :)

Comment: Are you mavenizing an exiting project or creating a new project ?

Comment: I am mavenizing an existing project

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MyEclipse, rather than just eclipse, with the m2e plugin. Also, I'm assuming the latest release of MyEclipse (2015 CI). If these assumptions are correct, note that the facet your are adding is for Maven Support of Java EE projects, which is why it is asking for the web project facet version. If you simply want to convert a java project to a maven project, right click on the project then select Configure->Convert to Maven project.

Comment: yes I am using MyEclipse (2013 SR2). And I am trying to add maven support for JEE project, but it is asking me to add Dynamic Web Module. What I want is simply to convert this project Maven project, unfortunately, I did not find that "Configure" Menu :(

Comment: OK, I'd definitely recommend upgrading to 2015 CI (no additional license needed) as full support for 2013 will end when the GA 2015 is released. However,for now, there are two approaches. Either let the wizard add the Dynamic Web Project facet (not sure why you wouldn't want that for a JEE project) during the process of adding the Maven Facet. Or go to Window->Preferences->General->Capabilities->Advanced then expand the MyEclipse Standard node and enable the WTP deprecated (yes, deprecated) capability, click OK. Now you will see the Configure project menu item as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: the idea is that this project contains only model's classes, adding the dynamic web module will add new "unwanted" resources to the project like WebApp directory and its contents. I can just delete them after adding the Web Module and change the maven to build the project as JAR not WAR, but I don't know why I should do that when it is really possible to convert the project to Maven using command line and then import it back to workspace as Maven Project. I wish I am explaining my points clearly.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's possible to convert to a maven project, without the Java EE facets, as mentioned in my last comment. The Configure option is there as standard in release 2015 CI but has to be added in earlier releases via the method I gave.